# Rmarkdown editing + language highlighting in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, markdown, r

> R Markdown is an authoring format that enables easy creation of
>   dynamic documents, presentations, and reports from R

([source](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/))

it is developped and supported by RStudio.
I am looking for a custom style that would ease Rmarkdown edition in NotePad ++ that I find more convenient to use. would you know if this is available ?

Answer (score 2):

There are three components to editing and using Rmarkdown in npp. I'll say up front that I do not use npp much, though I recommend it in place of other language-specific editors (e.g., GAMSide, standard notepad, wordpad), specifically with programming in mind.

#### Syntax Highlighting

On github, I found an older [markdown syntax highlighter for npp](https://github.com/jjchiw/markdown_npp), and at least two forks ([here](https://github.com/Edditoria/markdown_npp_zenburn) and [here](https://github.com/Hyzual/markdown_npp)), though none of them appear to have any activity in the last couple of years. This does not mean they aren't good, but since a markdown (CommonMark?) standard has adjusted in the last couple of years, so it's possible or likely that they will not display everything accurately.

#### Preview

There are several conversations on npp's forums, specifically [this one](http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/482781/thread/f8136239/) which discusses a npp plugin that provide previews. I think there were some discussions that it may not work in some configurations, but it's a start. One side-effect (I think) is that it uses a specific renderer (Cpp-Markdown) vice the same renderer that Rstudio uses ([pandoc](http://pandoc.org)). Since the plugin's render goes to HTML only, its usefulness to you is conditional on your needs.

#### Processing

None of this so far actually addresses your use of inline code blocks and processing it. To do that, I'd recommend simply setting up a macro to render the current `.Rmd` file for you in the current directory. One way for doing this:

1. In NPP, select "Run" and type in `Rscript.exe -e "setwd('$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)'); rmarkdown::render('$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)')"` (fixing the path to Rscript as necessary). Optionally provide additional arguments to `render` as needed, such as to force a specific output format. (This latter point can permit you to use one hotkey to render to PDF and another to render to HTML.)
2. Give it a name, such as "Render Rmd to PDF".
3. Give it a hotkey that is not otherwise used. (This latter point takes a little bit of research and/or trial and error.)

You can similarly set up a "View Rendered Doc" macro (different hotkey) that opens to resulting file, using a command of something like: `SumatraPDF.exe $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)/$(NAME_PART).pdf`. (I use [Sumatra PDF](http://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/download-free-pdf-viewer.html) for several reasons, a prominent one being that it recognizes when the pdf file has been updated it and updates automatically, not a feature of AcroRead. With this, you open the pdf once and keep it open and it updates on each re-rendering.)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Better in **SynWRite** editor, create new lexer, based on Markdown (copy Markdown to new name), and correct it in the "Lexer properties" dialog.